# How to make a single row in db have 2 rows in output depending on its column values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have an items table in the database that can have a maximum of 2 units, sample below:

| item_name | unit_1 | unit_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pencil | pc | pc |
| ballpen | pc | box |
| notebook | pc | pc |

If an item only has 1 unit, then unit_1 and unit_2 is the same.

Is there a way to output it like this:

| item_name | unit |
| --- | --- |
| pencil | pc |
| ballpen | pc |
| ballpen | box |
| notebook | pc |

So the ballpen who has 2 units, ended up having 2 rows. If an item has 1 unit, then it only has 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't state your DBMS, but the following is standard ANSI SQL (and tested in Postgres)

You can use a CROSS JOIN against a unique list of units:

```
select i.item_name, u.unit
from items i
  cross join lateral (
     values (i.unit_1) 
     union
     values (i.unit_2)
  ) as u(unit)
```

The UNION will in the derived table will return a single row if both units are the same and two rows if they are different. The CROSS JOIN then does the rest.

Another option is to use a UNION which will remove duplicate rows:

```
select item_name, unit_1 as unit
from items
union 
select item_name, unit_2
from items;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5194ef90e578117d04d8da47a56ab33b)

Comment: I use mySQL... is there a way to do cross join lateral with it?

Comment: If you are using MySQL, use the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
WITH tmp_1 AS(
  SELECT item_name, unit_1 as _unit, count(1) AS unit
  GROUPBY item_name, unit_1
), 
WITH tmp_2 AS
  SELECT item_name, unit_2 as _unit, count(1) AS unit
  GROUPBY item_name, unit_2
),
WITH tmp_3 AS (
  SELECT item_name, unit
  FROM tmp_1
  UNION(
    SELECT item_name, unit
    FROM tmp_2
  )
)
SELECT DISTINCT *  FROM tmp_3
```

Comment: If all the syntax errors are fixed, this will simply display a unique list of items with the number `1` as the second column. The `count()` serves no purpose in the CTEs and the final DISTINCT is useless as the previous `UNION` will have done that already.